# Nginx php files are downloading instead of execute

Tags: php, nginx, centos7, centos6

I'v configured Ngnix server on CentOs 7 and it is working find with html but when I'm trying to open .php file it is downloaded. 
I'm using Php7.2.
Here is my configuration(I'm using 123.123.123.123 instead my real ip):

```
server {
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        listen 123.123.123.123:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/example.com/public_html;
        index index.php index.html;

        server_name 123.123.123.123;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

So when I'm trying to access to 123.123.123.123/test/index.php I'm geting file download.

How could I force ngnix to execute php files?

Answer (score 1):

You also need fastcgi_pass:

```
location ~ \.php$ {        
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;         
  fastcgi_index index.php;         
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;        
  include fastcgi_params; 
  }
```

Comment: And what ip and port I should set?

Comment: Since PHP-FPM runs in the same machine, 127.0.0.1 is correct. The port is by default 9000. See configuration files at /etc/php-fpm.d